# Get selected text from google docs

Tags: google-docs

I'm developing a system for my company. I am opening .doc files on Google document viewer in an iFrame on a webpage and editing the file. In some case, I need to copy the selected text from google docs (in Iframe) and paste it to a textbox  (outside of iFrame).

Is that possible?

It would also be great if I changed the backgroundcolor of the selected text.

Many thanks.

Comment: I'm sorry if I'm doing wrong by posting again but nobody knows?

Comment: I need to do the exact same thing.  Have you gotten anywhere?  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15722712/need-to-highlight-and-copy-text-from-google-doc-viewer-to-clipboard

Comment: Try and look at the answer to this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41419141/capture-text-selection-in-google-docs